# solr/browse (solritas) page for searching pdf files

Tags: solr

I have indexed random pdf files. I have no variety of fields. I take the whole content of the file as attr_content field. Now i have to use solr/browse and I expect it to be same as how it works for the example files present in the exampledocs directory. is that possible? I am new to solr. so pls suggest me in brief. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You may want to edit the "/browse" section in solrconfig.xml to match the fields in your collection(i.e you may consider to use attr_content instead of text field), and don't forget to edit the velocity templates, usually under the "conf\velocity" directory.

Alternatively, if you are not familiar with velocity engine, [ajax-solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) is a nice project that provides a nice UI for starters.